# Potentially asbestos?

Tags: insulation, remodeling, asbestos

So we're doing a tear-out of the second half of our kitchen, and we came across some old batt insulation in the wall chases from the forty eight company(one of the companies sued out of business from the class-action mesothelioma litigation). The house was built in 1872, but it was extended twice, once in 1910, and once again around 1940. This area is in the 1940s extension.

I've read online that batt rolls rarely contain asbestos, but I was wondering if anyone who has dealt with this specific brand before knows if it contains asbestos or not? It's greyish in color. The insulation itself says 'copr-fibre', but I can't find any information about it.

[image: insulation]

[image: insulation]

[image: insulation]

Answer (score 2):

This may get you on the right track:
"The Forty-Eight Insulations Company was founded in 1923 in East Aurora, Illinois. Forty-Eight sought to produce high-quality insulation." "Forty-Eight used asbestos until 1982, long after it was known that the mineral was toxic. The Forty-Eight Insulation Qualified Settlement Trust was created to compensate the victims of Forty-Eight. Two separate amounts were placed into the trust fund. The first was $39 million to resolve existing claims. The second was $15 million for future claims."

You have a local testing lab that can sample the material and give you an answer.  In my area the test runs about $50.

Comment: Asbestos is not toxic , it is carcinogenic.